# CMake: Could NOT find CSharp in Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, malmo

CMake newbie here!

I'm trying to build Malmo project on my linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04) following https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo/blob/master/doc/build_linux.md

However I'm stuck at cmake command: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

The error that I'm getting is  Could NOT find CSharp (missing: CSHARP_TYPE CSHARP_VERSION CSHARP_COMPILER). Below is the full error message.

```
aerin@aerin-HP-Z230-Tower-Workstation:~/MalmoPlatform/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   iostreams
--   program_options
--   python
--   regex
--   system
--   thread
--   atomic
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CSharp (missing: CSHARP_TYPE CSHARP_VERSION CSHARP_COMPILER)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindCSharp.cmake:67 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:121 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/aerin/MalmoPlatform/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/aerin/MalmoPlatform/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How do I make cmake to find Csharp here?

Comment: Maybe you could start by installing Mono.

Comment: Thanks @Beefster installing Mono resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Beefster advice. Installing mono resolved the issue.

1. Add the Mono repository to your system
   (Ubuntu 16.04)

   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

   echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list

   sudo apt-get update
2. Install Mono

   sudo apt-get install mono-devel

Comment: AFAIK [mono-devel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mono-devel) is already in 16.04LTS